# Postgres error 23505: Key (extname)=(pgcrypto) already exists

Tags: node.js, postgresql

Using `graphile-worker` to schedule jobs and storing the information in postgres. Whenever I create a new instance of postgres and just after that I create a new DB, I keep getting this error.

```
{
  "length": 229,
 "name": "error",
 "severity": "ERROR",
 "code": "23505",
 "detail": "Key (extname)=(pgcrypto) already exists.",
 "schema": "pg_catalog",
 "table": "pg_extension",
 "constraint": "pg_extension_name_index",
 "file": "nbtinsert.c",
 "line": "656",
 "routine": "_bt_check_unique",
 "level": "error",
 "message": "========> duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"pg_extension_name_index\"",   
            "stack": "error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"pg_extension_name_index\"\n
            at Parser.parseErrorMessage (/home/baqir/WebstormProjects/nektar/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:287:98)    at Parser.handlePacket (/home/baqir/WebstormProjects/nektar/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:126:29)\n 
            at Parser.parse (/home/baqir/WebstormProjects/nektar/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/parser.js:39:38)\n
            at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/baqir/WebstormProjects/nektar/node_modules/pg-protocol/dist/index.js:11:42)\n    
            at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28)\n    
            at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)\n    
            at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:289:9)\n    
            at Socket.Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:228:10)\n    
            at TCP.onStreamRead (node:internal/stream_base_commons:199:23)"
}
```

I have tried using  diffrent versions of postgres using docker, even tried to create an instance on AWS. Its always the same error.

My team however, they just create the DB and start the workers and graphile does the migrations by itself. I do not understand what is wrong here.

Comment: Perhaps a much better source would be your team members. What are you doing/not doing that is different from whet they are doing/not doing.

Answer (score 2):

You get this error when two sessions try to create the same extension at the exact same time. (If they aren't at the same time, then you get a friendlier error message, or no error at all if the create was done with "IF NOT EXISTS").

So apparently you are launching two things to do the same (or overlapping) migrations at the same time, while your colleagues are not.